# How to avoid long path to class name in the __module__ property?

Tags: python

I am writing python library with the following structure:

```
src
  mylib
    __init__.py
    mylib.py
    utils.py
```

I have a class `MyClass` defined in the `mylib.py`. I want to be able to import it by the user as `from mylib import MyClass`. Inside `__init__.py` I put `from .mylib import MyClass`.

Everything works but the import location look ugly (it is probably taken from `MyClass.__module__`):

```
from mylib import MyClass
print(MyClass)  # <class 'mylib.mylib.MyClass'>
```

Why do I have duplication `mylib.mylib` in the output and how to avoid it? My dumb solution is to put all my library code into `__init__.py` but it feels there should be a better solution.

For example, when you do the same with [PyTorch](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch) library

```
from torch import Tensor
print(Tensor)  # <class 'torch.Tensor'>
```

There is no such duplication, even though I would expect `<class 'torch._tensor.Tensor'>` since it is [imported](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/b0a631c/torch/__init__.py#L649) from file `_tensor.py`.

Comment: It says `mylib.mylib` because that's the actual module the class is defined in. Does it *really* matter…?

Comment: @deceze From the practical standpoint, it doesn't matter and makes sense. However, it seems that I am missing some important best-practice in exposing my library API.